# Replacing Variable in Properties file in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, properties-file

I have a properties file which has a environment variable which I am trying to replace with the actual value from shell script.
Here's my properties file:

```
host=${HOST}
other=otherValue
```

How can I change the ${HOST} in the properties file and rewrite the to the new file or the same file from the shell script?

Comment: check `envsubst`

Answer (score 1):

You just read the property file and eval the line, by doing so the environment variable is replaced. Example:

```
while read line; do
  eval echo $line
done < property_file.txt
```

Look ma, no external commands!

Comment: this is a great way! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/\$\{(\w+)\}/$ENV{$1}/' input_file > output_file
```

Or change the same file, saving the old one with extension `.bak`:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\$\{(\w+)\}/$ENV{$1}/' input_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$ENV{$1}/` : Change strings that look like variable names into their values. Specifically, `\$` is a literal dollar sign, `\{` and `\}` are literal braces (all of them escaped). `(\w+)` is one or more word characters, with parenthesis around to capture this pattern and save it into the first capture variable, `$1`. The entire pattern that was just matched (something that looks like `${...}`) is replaced with the value of the corresponding environmental variable.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)